# how to use updatepanel in repeater?

Tags: triggers, textbox, updatepanel, repeater, scriptmanager

I have to use updatepanel in repeater. When I change values in textbox, I want to see change eval("fiyat") values without postback.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="gel" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Repeater ID="tum_sepet" runat="server" OnItemCreated="tum_sepet_ItemCreated">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <td style="width: 147px; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px solid #dbdbdb;">
                                <div class="ok_sepet_urun_fiyat"><%# Convert.ToDecimal ( Eval("fiyat")).ToString("#,##0.00") %> <%# Eval("parabirim") %></div>
                            </td>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox1" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Code

```
protected void tum_sepet_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1");
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(control);
    }
```

I make this process in .cs eval("fiyat") = price * number(TextBox1.Text).
Any Ideas ?